# How do I parameterize a DB2 ODBC query using C#?

Tags: c#, odbc, db2

I have a problem trying to parameterize some "dynamic" SQL build in an existing C# class used by an ASP app. The environment is:

- Win Server 2008
- .NET 3.0
- C#
- DB2 9.x ([IBM][CLI Driver][DB2])

The existing code just concatenates the SQL with the param strings in a long SQL string - which is of course at risk for SQL injection. As is my practice whenever I see this, I tend to change the code to use parameters. But with this code I am failing. I have tried "@" and I have tried "?" - the latter is what I understand to be necessary for ODBC.

Here is a simplified code snippet (forgive me if I don't format it right - this is my first question) that I have compiled and run:

```
private DataSet test(String schemaName )
{
        String sortField = "TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME";
        String sortDirection = "ASC";
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[schemaName] + dbUser;
        try
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = connStr;
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ? ? ");
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(sortField);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(sortDirection);                              
            logger.log("cmd SQL = \t" + cmd.CommandText );

            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);

            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Data.Add("Location:", "test()");
            ex.Data.Add("Connection", conn.ConnectionString);
            logger.logException(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Log printout:

cmd SQL =   SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ? ?

Where TABLE_NAME is of course the table I am querying.

What I get in return is this (some proprietary info removed:

> EXCEPTION occured at 4/26/2012 12:29:41 PM ERROR [42601] [IBM][CLI
>   Driver][DB2] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "?" was found following "".
>   Expected tokens may include:  "MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND
>   MINUTES MINUTE HOURS".  SQLSTATE=42601
>       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)Connection    Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};
>   .....

Changing this to a stored proc is not allowed.

Upgrading to a later version of .NET is not allowed.

Changing/upgrading the ODBC driver is not allowed.

What I am seeing indicates to me that the "?" parameter is not being replaced.

I have tried AddWithValue() and I have tried Add(OdbcType.VarChar).Value = sortField (or something to that effect).

I am kind of at my whit's end - all of the googling and searching here indicates to me that the code above should work, but so far I have not been able to get the parameters in the SQL substituted with the variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, and I have tried "new OdbcParameter(...)" too.

Comment: I don't believe what you are trying is real parameters. "FieldName = ?" is a parameter. In this case you would build the query as: " ... ORDER BY " + sortField + " " + sortDirection

Comment: Not SQL parameters, but rather substituting C# params into the SQL to protect against SQL injection. My example is simplified, but the real query contains strings that the user can enter. I want to protect the SQL against parents who name their children "Bobby Tables" ("Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--").

Comment: But the sort order and direction are coming from code, not user input. So concat is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `?` is an unexpected token is because you are using it in the `ORDER BY` clause (which I don't think is allowed).

The reason to use parameters is to mitigate the risks of user input. When building your query, if the `ORDER BY` field and direction are not coming via user input, you are safe in building the query with concatenation.

Only use the `?` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = ? ORDER BY " + sortField + " " + sortDirection);
```

Comment: You are right. I had just simplified my example a little too much.

Comment: And yes, once I used "FieldName = ?" in the rest of the query, it started working as expected. Now I need to find out if I can sub the column and schema names (both of which are variable). I suspect not, but they are not supplied by user input and they are relatively safe in that they are supplied by calling code.

Comment: I suspect most ORMs build the non-user supplied parts using concat, but then switch to parameters for the user values. I understand what you want to accomplish, but I don't think ODBC (which has a very low feature implementation rate) is going to support you.

Comment: Thanks. I have a pattern I used in both Java and C# where I am stuck with SQL in the code; I usually create a static string using a String builder to create most of the static portion of the query so it doesn't have to get built every time the query is called, then I append to it any remaining dynamic portion of the string. I also want to use params where I can naturally - for those parts where the caller is supplying some variable part of the query.